# Двумерный массив (ввод размера NxN)

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Почему нельзя так делать:

```
scanf("%d", &N);
int A[N][N];
```

Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что такое умеют далеко не все компиляторы, в частности, VC++ - не умеет.

У него наиболее простой обходной путь -

```
int ** A;
A = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    A[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

Прелесть данного решения - в возможности обращений `A[i][j]`, как к обычному двумерному массиву.

Только надо не забыть потом освободить всю память - в обратном порядке.

Comment: А `alloca` можно? По сути то же выделение массива на стеке.

Comment: @Arhad Да можно, конечно, только вот как-то *"не приучен мусорить на палубе" (с) "Полосатый рейс"* - в стеке массивы держать... Поэтому даже не подумал :)